# Remove timezone during POSIXlt Conversion in R

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, posixlt

I have a column in my dataframe as datetime (factor) with the values as "15-10-2017 16:41:00".

I wanted this data to be converted as "2017-10-15 16:41:00".
When i try to convert this, I'm getting the timezone also as output.

I tried using `tz=""`, `usetz=F` but no use.
Any suggestions?

Code:

```
as.POSIXlt("15-10-2017 16:41:00",format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2017-10-15 16:41:00 IST"
```

Answer (score 7):

From the help page of `as.POSIXlt`:

*"" is the current time zone*

which is the default.

That's why it does not work. You could remove the timezone information this way, and it will not show while printing:

```
my_datetime <- as.POSIXlt("15-10-2017 16:41:00",format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
my_datetime$zone <- NULL
my_datetime
```

but I don't understand why you would want to do that. You should convert to GMT if you don't want to worry about the timezone. Also `lubridate` package has a nice `force_tz` function if you have to force some specific timezones.

Answer (score 5):

If you are ok storing the datetime as a character instead of as a POSIXlt, then you can use `strftime()`:

```
my_datetime <- as.POSIXlt("15-10-2017 16:41:00",format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
strftime(my_datetime)
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this:

```
strip.tz <- function(dt) {
  fmt <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  strptime(strftime(dt, format = fmt, tz=""), format = fmt, tz="UTC")
}
```

and you would use it like this:

```
my_datetime <- as.POSIXct("15-10-2017 16:41:00",format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
strip.tz(my_datetime)
```